# How to resolve warnings field name does not match the regular expression in scala

Tags: scala

I have following statements:

```
val summarizationList = Map(4 -> "Monthly", 3 -> "Weekly", 2 -> "Daily", 1 -> "Hourly")

val Type: Int = summarizationList.find(_._2 == lastSummarizationDate._1._1).get._1

val SummarizedDate = (lastSummarizedDate.toList.sortBy(_._2) ++ Map("End" -> end)).sliding(2)
      .map(a => (a(0), a(1))).toList
```

In last two statements am getting "Field name does not match the regular expression '^[a-z][A-Za-z0-9]*$'"

How to resolve following warnings?

Comment: What are `lastSummarizationDate` and `lastSummarizedDate` ?

Answer (score 2):

```
scala>  "Type".matches("^[a-z][A-Za-z0-9]*$")
res0: Boolean = false
scala>  "SummarizedDate".matches("^[a-z][A-Za-z0-9]*$")
res1: Boolean = false
scala>  "type".matches("^[a-z][A-Za-z0-9]*$")
res2: Boolean = true
scala>  "summarizedDate".matches("^[a-z][A-Za-z0-9]*$")
res3: Boolean = true
```

for your variable name should be started with lowercase character.